# git command to check if a repository has any uncommitted changes

Tags: branch, git

I need to know if there is a git command using which I can check if there are any uncommitted changes present in a branch for a given repository

Comment: how about `git status` ?

Comment: Uncommitted changes are not in any branch; branches only refer to commits.  The uncommitted changes are in the index and/or the working tree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are only interested in files which are part of the index, the following command shows concise info

```
git status -suno
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Developer_cheatsheet_for_git

refer this link for git commands.

**show uncommited local changes:**

```
 git diff [file]
```

Comment: can I get number of files tat are not yet committed ?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

To show uncommitted changes in files that are already part of the index as well as in untracked files, use `git status -s`

Answer (score -1):

You might as well use  [gitk - The Git repository browser](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)

Comment: You might be using this as part of a script.  This answer is poor