# Git: Switch to local repository from working directory

Tags: git

As far I have understood, there are three stages in git workflow -

1. Working directory which is actual local project workspace with .git file.
2. Staging area where files are added from Working directory to be commited.
3. Local repository where files are commited from the Staging area.

Suppose I have commited several files from the working directory. Those commited files will be in the local repository. Now, I need verify if all the required files are commited by running the project. How can I switch to local repository for running the code to verify commited changes before pushing them to remote?

For example, consider there are 3 files in the working directory - one.js, two.js, three.js and all the files are modified, but only two of them - one.js and two.js needs to be commited which contains inter-dependent changes. But suppose I only commit one.js and forgot to commit two.js and because of this the app will be broken in the local repository. For this case, I need to run and verfiy the app from local repository which contains only commited changes and not all the changes unlike working directory. How to achieve this?

Comment: Your assumption that the app would be (after a partial commit) broken locally seems wrong to me, as files themselves (in the working dir) are the same before and after being commited. What will be different is the remote state, because one of the files will **not** have been modified *there*.

Comment: Yes, that is the thing. I need to identify the partial commit only. I meant that the app will be broken at the remote. But is there any way to identify this after commiting and before pushing changes to remote by running the app?

Comment: Not by running the app, no, but by inspecting the branch. For start, a simple `git status` will output any uncommited changes.

Comment: Okay, was aware of this. That means we can inspect this at code level only and not practically by running the app. Was curious regarding this because there might be a scenario where there are large number of files to be commited and we might think some file which has small interdependent change which is required to be commited as not required for commit and will cause the app to be broken at the remote.

Comment: Oh! Sorry I now get what you meant... yes you can test the remote branch locally, I'm writing a short answer about it right now.

Comment: I do not think that there is any way to verify that your commit with partial implementation of the app, will break on the remote. Committing revertable commits is upto you. I know that you are supposed to commit only working application but you can also use certain convention to separate out working commits from the other, like for example `WIP` in your commit message automatically tells that, reverting to this comment will probably cause the app to respond in unexpected ways.

Comment: Ok, backtracking again on my part.... wanna [discuss it](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199683/for-abhinandan)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git command to check if a repository has any uncommitted changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946332/git-command-to-check-if-a-repository-has-any-uncommitted-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that git has three storage areas - the work tree, the staging area (sometimes called the index), and what you refer to as the local repository[1] (the collection of objects, including `COMMIT`s, that make up the project history - normally called the database).

But of those, the only one you can compile, run, or load into a text editor is the working directory.  So rather than "switch to the local repository" as you put it, what you would need to do to run the committed version is update the worktree (or, at least *a* worktree - there can be more than one) to match the committed version.

How exactly to do that depends on circumstances, and the situation you outlined is actually a little odd (and likely to cause you other, unrelated problems), which makes it hard to give a detailed answer.

First of all, the idea that "I've changed 3 files but only 2 of them need to be committed"...  That's usually a sign of a problem waiting to happen.  If the third file is not in the repo at all and is listed in `.gitignore`, it can be ok; but all else being equal, you are better off when your worktree is as close as possible to being just a reflection of the content you're committing.

If that third file isn't committed / is ignored, then you can use `git status` to confirm whether you've committed everything else.  It will tell you which files have staged changes, which have unstaged changes, which have never been committed, etc.  You can use `git diff` to get more detail about what changes have not been staged (or `git diff --staged` to see those that *have* been staged but not committed).

But to really know that what you've committed works, you need to "check out" the committed version.

If you don't have uncommitted changes you need to preserve, this is easy - `git status` will tell you how to revert to the committed state.  (Generally `git reset -- :/:` and then `git checkout -- :/:` would work.)

If you do have uncommitted changes you need to preserve, you could stash them (but there are edge cases where that may not do exactly what you intend - e.g. if you have both staged and unstaged changes, you may end up in a situation where you get them all back unstaged).  See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Or you can use a separate clone of the repo for testing.  This is typical for build servers, but can also be done locally.  A slightly lighter-weight solution is to create a second worktree attached to your existing repo.  Docs supporting those options:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stage
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

---

[1] The "repository" usually is a term for the whole thing - all three storage areas.

Comment: I revisted the question myself and think that it is the responsibility of the person who commits to know if the commits are partial or not and if they would break the app or not. Also, we can follow best practices to avoid breaking/ partial commits by keeping the commits short, making branches for different implemetions so that all the files changes in a branch would be relating to a single implementaion and so we can commit them all reliably at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `git status` does not say:

`On branch Master
nothing to commit, working tree clean` ,

meaning you have some uncommited changes, then
if you want to see the state of only the commited content, you can stash the currently made modifications with

`git stash` ,

then the working directory is clean and the stash contains the unsaved changes.

To get those modifications back do

`git stash pop`

for more information on `stash` look [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: ...unless there are untracked files.  In that case you can do `git stash -u`.  Also, when you pop the stash, it will by default mix your staged and unstaged changes.  (You can *maybe* use `--index` with the pop command to avoid that, depending on circumstances...)  `stash` is great, but it's not really a great go-to recommendation to be given without more info to someone who is clearly not that experienced with git